# Detecting metadata-only read requests in windows filesystem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, dokan

I'm developing a kind of filesystem driver. All of read requests that windows makes to my filesystem goes by the driver implementation.

I would like to distinguish between "normal" read requests and those who want to get only the metadata from the file. ( Windows reads first 4K of the file and then stop reading ).

Does Windows mark this metadata reads in some way? It would be very useful in order to treat that two kind of operations in a different way.

In a typical CreateFile call, we have AccessMode, ShareMode, CreationDisposition and FlagsAndAttributes parameters ( being DWORD ), i'm not sure if it's possible to extract some clue of the operation requested.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: petitions -> partitions?

Comment: Well, indeed, what I what to distinguish is between normal read operations and metadata-only read operations. There is no partitions involved :)

Comment: I think he meant "requests" where he wrote "petitions". Pretty much the same in English, not in programmers jargon.

Comment: Thanks MSalters, thats what i wanted to mean :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to get the SysInternals file monitoring tool. It captures stacktraces for each call, and since it understands PDBs can even show you function names. That should allow you to figure out many details of this particular call.

Comment: I have checked Procmon ( now filemon is inside procmon ), and there are very little differences between that two kind of requests.
i don't find any clear evidence that can help me to distinguish the requests. :(

Comment: It then appears that the answer to your first question is "no"

Answer (score 0):

On rereading, it appears that the question is looking at the wrong place for an optimization. Why not treat every request for the first 4KB as a request for metadata? There is very little harm in that assumption.

An assumption the other way around would be harmful, if you're doing 100 MB of real I/O when you really only needed 4KB. But if you need 100 MB, a small optimization for the first 4KB causes at most a one-time small hickup for an inherently lengthy operation.

Comment: Actually that's is what i'm doing now. It's working but i'm not sure if it could have some more consecuencies.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Windows, but Windows Explorer that performs scanning of files to extract metadata. Moreover, you will also face the reads to create thumbnails.

Reporting the drive as a remote / network to Windows will make Explorer read less information and reduce load on the file system, but unfortunately there seems to be no way to block such reading completely.